# What is the best IPC technique which can guarantee mutual exclusion in perl?

Tags: perl, process, ipc, named-pipes, mutual-exclusion

I am working on a project where i need to set up a communication between parent process and child processes, i was using named pipes for IPC but i have heard that named pipes won't guarantee mutual exclusion.
What would be the best IPC technique which can guarantee mutual exclusion?

Comment: Can you describe issue in more details?

Comment: Actually parent process is assigning work between child processes and each child is picking a row from database table and performing some operation with it. Unfortunately it is hard for a child to know which row was already taken by other child. What technique should i use so that each child will pick a different row??

Comment: hi @mpapec, you got my question??

Comment: I would change approach and tell every child which row to pick.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Unix domain socket (`AF_UNIX`) with datagrams (`SOCK_DGRAM`) instead of a stream (this is kind of like a reliable, local UDP). That way you can multiplex sending and receiving without having to resort to locking.

An other alternative would be using message queues, but that's considered a bit obscure nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named pipes in combination with [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html)/[fcntl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fcntl.html) if you want mutual exclusion, but that's only workable when either the reader (preferably) or the writer end is singular (the end with multiple clients would use the locks).

Comment: both reader and writer end is non-singular. Is there any other IPC technique can be used here??